# flexible custom attribute,how to design table

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, modeling

my assignment is user's type,every type has many custom attribute.and every attribute have different display type ,different sub-attribute and value.
for example
i create a user type named "usertype1",its have different attribute
such as:"sex","hobby","synopsis"...
sex display type is "radio"
and its sub-attribute name is "man","women",respective value is 1,0

hobby display type is "checkbox" 
and its sub-attribute name is "singing","reading","cooking",respective value is 1,0,0

synopsis display type is "text",
it have no sub-attribute.

and user can have many checkbox type sub-attribute 
such use can singing and reading,but cannot cookding
and only one radio type sex or women,and user can have synopsis value or no.

all these attribute are dynamic,my design is

```
'CREATE TABLE `sys_user_type` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `creater` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `creation_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''1'',
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `describes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sys_user_type_name` (`name`),
  KEY `sys_user_type_creater` (`creater`),
  CONSTRAINT `sys_user_type_creater` FOREIGN KEY (`creater`) REFERENCES `sys_user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'


'CREATE TABLE `sys_user_type_ext` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_type_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''1'',
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `isnull` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''1'',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sys_user_type_ext_user_type_id` (`user_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sys_user_type_ext_user_type_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_type_id`) REFERENCES `sys_user_type` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

'CREATE TABLE `sys_user_type_ext_val` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_type_ext_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sys_user_type_ext_id_name` (`user_type_ext_id`,`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sys_user_type_ext_id_value` (`user_type_ext_id`,`value`),
  KEY `sys_user_type_ext_val_type_ext_id` (`user_type_ext_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sys_user_type_ext_val_type_ext_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_type_ext_id`) REFERENCES `sys_user_type_ext` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

'CREATE TABLE `sys_user_ext` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_type_ext_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `creation_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `value` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sys_user_ext_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `sys_user_ext_type_ext_id` (`user_type_ext_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sys_user_ext_type_ext_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_type_ext_id`) REFERENCES `sys_user_type_ext` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `sys_user_ext_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `sys_user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

but the sys_user_ext table,value column have problem
if type is checkbox,the value will have multiple value,which is separated by ",",like "1,2,3",but the separated value order cannot be guaranteed,it may be 2,3,1
and the value should be sys_user_type_ext_val table id or value.
[image]

my select page is like
[image]
i know the table design is terrible.
please help me and give me some suggestion.

Comment: You're reinventing a database inside a database. Your page is designed specifically, your data model should be the same - sys_user_type (id PK, mobile, idcard, sex, startlevel, position, supplement, birth, worktime_start, worktime_end). The database is already dynamic - you can create and alter tables anytime, so keep it simple.

Comment: So, each user type gets it's own dynamic form, and all the data to create the form's inputs should be stored in the database, is that correct?